# Moq - Setup return values of strongly typed class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

been trying to make a unit test using moq.

here's a class structure.

```
public interface IParameter<T> : IList<T>
{
}

public interface IParameters
{
    IParameter<string> Types;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public DataTable GetResult(IParameters parameters)
    {
        //do work here
        return dt;
    }
}

class TestMyClass
{
    [Test]
    public void TestGetResult()
    {
        var _mock = new Mock<IParameters>();
        _mock.SetUp(x => x.Types).Return(new [] {"1", "2"}); //Issue
        var m = new MyClass()
        var result = m.GetResult(_mock.Object)
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

i need to learn how to call _mock.SetUp properly so the property in IParameters return an IList type.

Alternately, I also tried this...

```
var mock = new Mock<IParameters>();
var mockparams = new Mock<IParameter<string>>(); 
mockparams.SetReturnsDefault( ); //What should i call to add { "1", "2", "3" } 
mock.Setup(x => x.ReportTypes).Returns(mockparams.Object);
```

so in mockparams what function should i call to set the return values?

Comment: return a list type, not the array. new List<string> {"1","2"}

Comment: that's just a pseudo code, assuming. but it should return type IParameter<string> and not just List<string>

Comment: What do you do with the `IParameters` in your `GetResult` method?

Comment: OK, when where is the implementation for IParameters? You will have to do it sooner or later

Comment: that should be irrelevant. but it's a parameter to query stuff.

Comment: @Hohhi the implementation if Iparameters shouldn't be required as this is a test method, unless what i'm trying to achieve with mocking won't work as i'm expecting then i will be creating an implementation specifically for testing purposes.

Comment: You should return smth of type IParameter<string>? Unless you return a mock of this type, you have to create an object of this type

Comment: yes, that's what IParameters class is expecting and I'm trying to manipute IParameters.Type property to return my expected set of values through mocking.

Comment: Then try this: 
            var mockParameter = new Mock<IParameter<string>>();
            _mock.Setup(x => x.Types).Returns(mockParameter.Object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BTW: Is `IParameters.Types` a property or a method?

You could just create a stub for the `IParameter` parameter, since you propably won't want to setup each method of IList:

```
class ParameterStub : List<String>, IParameter<String> { }
```

Then, mocking `IParameters` would be as simple as this:

```
...
var mock = new Mock<IParameters>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Types).Returns(new ParameterStub() {"1","2"});
var m = new MyClass();
var result = m.GetResult(mock.Object);
...
```

Comment: i was trying to put this as my final approach as i am too lazy to create a stub class just for testing.

i guess i am going to do this after all. thanks.

Comment: i'm marking this as answer for others who might have the same question, thinking if stubbing could be possible through mocking. or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You should mock IParameter and return mocked object instead of new [] {"1", "2"}

Comment: `var mock = new Mock<IParameters>();
var mockparams = new Mock<IParameter<string>>();
mockparams.SetReturnsDefault( ); //What should i call to add { "1", "2", "3" }
mock.Setup(x => x.ReportTypes).Returns(mockparams.Object);`


what function should i call to set value in the mockparams object

Comment: please don't post such much code as comment (nobody can read it). Better edit your question.